# PrimeFaces - Validation error in 2nd dropdown (dependent selectOneMenus) - RequestScoped

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

The 2nd dropdown is being populated by AJAX, but there's validation error in it. Even if the list is populated correctly and a selection is made.

```
<h:form id="form">
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" globalOnly="true" />

        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <p:outputLabel for="nome" value="Nome:" />
            <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{estadoMB.estado.nome}" required="true" validatorMessage="Nome incorreto!" />
            <p:message for="nome" />

            <p:outputLabel for="sigla" value="Sigla:" />
            <p:inputText id="sigla" value="#{estadoMB.estado.sigla}" maxlength="3" size="3" required="true" validatorMessage="Sigla incorreta!" />
            <p:message for="sigla" />

            <p:outputLabel for="continentes" value="Continente:" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="continentes" value="#{estadoMB.continenteId}" validatorMessage="Selecione um continente!"> <!-- required="# {not empty param[submit.clientId]}" binding="# {menuContinentes}" -->
                <f:selectItem  itemValue="" itemLabel="-- Selecione --" noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{continenteMB.continentes}" var="continente" itemLabel="#{continente.nome}" itemValue="#{continente.id}" />
                <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{estadoMB.onPaisesChange}" update="paises" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:message for="continentes" />

            <p:outputLabel for="paises" value="País:" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="paises" value="#{estadoMB.pais.id}" validatorMessage="Selecione um país!"> <!-- required="# {not empty param[menuContinentes.clientId]or not empty param[submit.clientId]}" -->
                <f:selectItem  itemValue="" itemLabel="-- Selecione --" noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{estadoMB.paisesCarregados}" var="pais" itemLabel="#{pais.nome}" itemValue="#{pais.id}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:message for="paises" />

            <p:commandButton action="#{estadoMB.save}" value="Salvar" update="@form" /> <!-- binding="# {submit}" -->
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

Method `onPaisesChange`:

```
public void onPaisesChange() {
    if(pais != null) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("id", getContinenteId());
        paisesCarregados = paisBean.findWithNamedQuery("Pais.findByContinenteId", map);
    }
    else {
        paisesCarregados = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Already tried EL binding; required="true" in both and I got the same result.

I think it's not possible to do what I want using request scoped beans...

Comment: *I think it's not possible to do what I want using request scoped beans* no, it isn't. Use `@ViewScoped` at least.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I can't, later, use ViewScoped, what should be done? Converters?

Comment: I don't understand why you cannot use `@ViewScoped` later. Please explain in detail your real problem.

Comment: I can use it right now (and it worked hehe thanks), but I'm also looking forward. I thought about "one selection per screen" when multiple selects are needed and the scope can't be changed for some reason. Something like "continent is selected, then click OK and select the country in the next screen".

Comment: Well, since the data won't be present in the same view, it's futile to talk about `@RequestScoped` to begin with. If you want/need to handle a flow, use `@FlowScoped` instead.

Comment: Completely forgot about FlowScoped. +1